# What is the correct way to connect the subspaces of a matrix to transpose vectors in the method of least squares?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, least-squares, projection-matrices

I'm studying linear algebra alone and having a hard time dealing with transpose vectors and their subspaces. The summary of what I saw is as follows:

- The row space of $A$ is the column space of $A^T$ and vice versa.
- The null space of $A=\{x\mid Ax=0,\ x^TA^T=0\}$ is the left null space of $A^T=\{x\mid A^Tx=0,\ x^TA=0\}$  and vice versa.
- If a solution of $Ax=b$ or $x^TA^T=b^T$ exists, $b$ is an element of column space of $A$ and row space of $A^T$.
- If a solution of $A^Tx=b$ or $x^TA=b^T$ exists, $b$ is an element of row space of $A$ and column space of $A^T$.
- The vector $x$ which minimizes $|b-Ax|$ causes $b-Ax$ to belong to the left null space of $A$. Therefore projection $b$ to column space of $A$ is $A\hat{x}=A((A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb)$.

My questions are:

- If $b$ is in column space of $A$, is $b^T$ in row space of $A$?
- Is the following statement correct?

  > The vector $x$ which minimizes $|b-A^Tx|$ causes $b-A^Tx$ to belong to the null space of $A$. Therefore projection $b$ to row space of $A$ is $A^T\hat{x}=A^T((AA^T)^{-1}Ab)$.
- How can I use $x^TA^T=b^T$ to describe the same as above? Does $b^T-x^TA^T$ belong to left null space of $A$? Which should I use, $A^Tx=b$ or $x^TA=b^T$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Q1: It's incorrect, since $b\in C(A)$ ($C$ for column space, $R$ for row space) $\Rightarrow b^{T}\in R(A^{T})$, which is generally different from $R(A)$. (Or to be brief, $b$ contains only the column information which isn't affected after transposition.)
- Q2: This is true by substituting $A$ with $A^T$ and $C(A^T)$ with $R(A)$. (Although the wordings in this question should be like $b-Ax\in ...$, rather than $|b-Ax|\in ...$)
- Q3: If $|b^T-x^TA^T|=|(b-Ax)^T|=|b-Ax|$ is minimalized, then $b-Ax$ belongs to the left null space of A, thus $A^T(b-Ax)=0\Rightarrow (b^T-A^Tx^T)A=0$, so this statement is also true.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've heard about "The row space of $A$ is the same as the column space of $A^T$" and which seems natural by the definition of a matrix. How is this different from the first question?

Comment: If you changed the wording to 'If $b$ is in the column space of $A$, $b^T$ is in the row space of $A^T$', then it should be the same as that in your comment, yet generally $R(A)\neq R(A^T)$ (maybe it's a typo in your question?).

Comment: I also feel these questions are strange, but I think I'm confused the meaning of "same". I mean, I thought it was an expression like this: $C(A)=R(A^T),\ a\in C(A)\implies a\in R(A^T)$, not $a^T\in R(A^T)$. You have informed me that this is wrong.

Comment: Maybe it's a little different, but I also doubt that I understand row space. I'm not sure what it means to have a solution in the row space of $A$. This seems to mean that the linear combination of the rows forms a solution of $Ax=b$. Is it only indirectly understood by the fact that it is an orthogonal complement of a null space? Can I say that the coefficient of linear combination has no other meaning when solution is in row space?

Comment: I see what you mean. In some textbooks rowspaces consist of column vectors, yet in some (like what I've read) consist of row vectors. Thus there may be some discrepancies in notations between these two interpretations (although isomorphic, so your comment is correct). And for the second question, a direct implication would be $Ax=b, x\in R(A)\Rightarrow \exists y, x=A^Ty\Rightarrow AA^Ty=b$, meaning that $AA^Tx=b$ has a nonzero solution.